# High Performance MySQL

Tags: mysql

A coworker handed me a copy of [High Performance MySQL by Jeremy D. Zawodny and Derek J. Balling](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067).  The book (published by O'Reilly) has a publish date of 2004.  I haven't found an updated edition.  My question is how reliable is the information at this time?

For example, the authors make the statement "MySQL will only ever use one index per table query".  Is this still true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the things are still applicable and as you know there is a 2nd edition available out which you might want to consider. I, personally, would start with this one then move on to the 2nd edition. I find the 1st edition relatively easier to study than the 2nd edition.

Answer (score 0):

Your edition is still plenty up to date.  If you are just starting out you won't be led astray.  If you start to wonder what has been updated, go to the book's  [page](http://oreilly.com/pub/pr/2031).  When you start to ask more advanced questions about optimization go onto amazon and get a used, up to date edition.  They're ~$35 and usual in mint condition.

Answer (score 0):

The original book is fantastic and is incredibly accurate.  Just as is the case w/any other piece of software - MySQL continues to evolve and so it is not a bad idea to get the most recent version; I bought one for every member of my development team.

[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/0596101716/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259440766&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716)

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found an updated edition.

There is a second edition of the book (released in 2008): http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/